# Multiple Hibernate envers FirstLevelCache instances

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have been debugging some strange envers behaviour in my code for a couple of days and have stumbled on something that surprised me. I have confirmed that this is not contributing to my problem but I thought that it would be worth checking my assumptions anyway.

If I get the current Hibernate session in multiple places in a single thread (I am using thread session context) I will always get the same session and therefore I will hit the same level one cache.

I had assumed similar behaviour with envers when getting an audit reader instance. I am using `AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(session);` to get `AuditReader` instances. I noticed that every time this is called (even within the same session context) I get a new audit reader instance, containing a unique first level cache instance.

It looks like this would result, at best, in the performance hit of multiple, possibly overlapping caches.

I had assumed that, for a session context, I would always get the same `AuditReader` instance and therefore, a single first level cache. I cannot think of a reason why this would not be the case.

This leaves me with four possibilities:

1. I am not using the correct method to get a session context's audit reader
2. There is a good reason for having multiple audit reader instances
3. There is a bug somewhere in the depths of envers
4. It does not make sense to reuse audit reader instances.

Can someone please provide some insight on this.

Thanks.

Comment: how is the session being bound to the thread and how are you reading from it... i know its a simple task but big issues arise there... in other words, pls share the code which is in question.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma I have a single static instance of `SessionFactory` and use `final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to get the current Hibernate context session.

Comment: how are you binding the Session to a thread and accessing it.. there could be something wrong there..

Comment: Hi @AnanthaSharma I am not sure what you mean. I am leaving Hibernate to manage the session contexts. I am just nominating thread context management by setting the configuration property `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to `thread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `AuditReaderFactory` ([here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/364a47f2c746a5eeb1642102580a9daa8bc27fc9/hibernate-envers/src/main/java/org/hibernate/envers/AuditReaderFactory.java)), a new instance of an `AuditReaderImpl` is created on each call; the instances are not cached anywhere themselves.

It isn't also specified anywhere that you should get the same instance given the same session; so your request can be treated as a "feature request", but I wouldn't say it's a bug.

There's no specific reason not to reuse same audit reader instances.

Comment: Thanks @adamw I will bare this in mind. In fact, thinking about this more, a first level cache of historical entities is very different to a first level cache of current entities as historical entities are immutable. Therefore a single cache could be considered for historical entities, regardless of session, which would require an ageing strategy. Considering this, it's probably much easier to stick with the current strategy :)